# Are these PPs or non-finite clauses – or something else entirely?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases, for-to-complementizers

I'm wondering about the construction ***for* [NP] *to* [VP]**, as illustrated in the following examples:

(1) I waited **for you to come here**

(2) He arranged **for me to go there**

(3) **For him to do that** took courage

(4) **For you to apologise** is not enough

My questions are:

- what is this construction from a formal point of view? I can't see how *for* can be anything other than a preposition, which would suggest that it is a PP – but prepositions can't take infinitive clauses as complements, can they?
- if it's not a PP, but rather a non-finite clause, then what function does *for* have in the clause, and what is *for* from a formal point of view?
- are we dealing with the same formal construction in all four examples?
- what are the functions of the relevant construction in (1) and (2)?

Comment: I think the last two do have a non-finite clause forming an NP, standing as subject. I don't think that is the case in the first two. In the second, I think that _for me_ and _to go there_  are separate argument of _arranged_. I am less confident about the first, but it is clearly not the same as the third and fourth, because even if it is a clause functioning as a NP, that does not include the _for_.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for your quick answer! I was thinking the same as you about (2), but isn't _me_ the subject of _go_? In that case they should belong to the same constituent, no? Also, I agree, of course, that the relevant construction functions as subject in (3) and (4), but if they are non-finite clauses, what is the form and function of _for_?

Comment: This was discussed here: [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481265/usage-of-infinitive-or-gerund/481303#481303)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) would say that all four of your boldfaced phrases are *to*-infinitivals with an overt subject. For CGEL, the *for* is not a preposition there, but a 'subordinator'.

On p. 1177 of CGEL, we find the following:

> [16]  i  *I wanted to arrange for Kim to do it.*
>
> In [i] we have a chain of three verbs, with *for Kim to do it* complement of *arrange* and *to arrange for Kim to do it* complement of *want*. We apply the term 'catenative' both to the non-finite complement and to the verb in the matrix clause that licenses it, so that *want* and *arrange* here belong to the class of catenative verbs. The last verb in the chain, *do*, is not a catenative verb as it does not have a non-finite complement.

A bit later on, CGEL explains that

*for Kim to do it*

is a *to*-infinitival with an overt subject. According to CGEL (p. 1178),

> *To*-infinitivals containing a subject are always introduced by the subordinator *for*:
>
> [20]  i  *[**For them** to withdraw now] would be a mistake.*                                           [subject] 
>            ii  *It's not necessary [**for them** to wait any longer].*                        [extraposed subject] 
>           iii  *The best plan would be [**for them** to go alone].*                              [predicative comp] 
>           iv  *I can think of no solution except [**for them** to sack him].*        [comp of preposition]

Comment: What’s the difference between *expect **for** things to improve* and *expect things to improve*? Is that *for* part of *expect for*, or is it part of the infinitive? You can do the same thing with *need **for** him to call* and *need him to call*, so I imagine there are others like this. You can *ask **that** he call you* and you can *ask **for** him to call you*, but you ask also *ask him to call you*. How come a *for* isn’t mandatory here in these *to*-infinitives with overt subjects?

Comment: @tchrist, the answer to your question is "Just because".

Comment: Put not your trust in CGEL.  See Peter Rosenbaum's https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/grammar-english-predicate-complement-constructions

Comment: @tchrist I don't think I'll have time today to come up with an answer that does full justice to your questions. At a glance, I need to bring together several threads from CGEL, from quite a few pages, and that's not a small project. For now, let me note that a major part of your question seems to be about constituent structure. Let me concentrate on that aspect for now.

Comment: @tchrist (I'm not saying I know for a fact I will succeed in giving a full CGEL answer to your questions, much less in convincing you that that's the correct answer. I'm merely saying that even attempting such an answer is a pretty big project, at least for me. I definitely don't have CGEL in my little finger.)

Comment: @tchrist (Ooops, I see that there was a discussion on some of that in the thread under your answer... I'll continue there.)

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, we have no prepositions today!

There aren’t any prepo­si­tional phrases here, be­cause al­though one
typ­i­cally iden­ti­ﬁes the words *to* and *for* as prepo­si­tions, they
are here func­tion­ing not as prepo­si­tions but as com­ple­men­tiz­ers of in­ﬁni­tive clauses.

Your sen­tences 1 and 2 do not con­tain prepo­si­tional phrases be­cause
they are phrasal verbs (*to wait for, to ar­range for*) whose com­ple­ments
are in­ﬁni­tive clauses with overt subjects:

- (1) I [waited for]<sup>*phrasal verb*</sup> [you to come here.]<sup>*in­ﬁni­tive clause*</sup>
- (2) He [ar­ranged for]<sup>*phrasal verb*</sup> [me to go there.]<sup>*in­ﬁni­tive clause*</sup>

Those two uses of *for* are no more prepo­si­tional than the two uses of *to*
are.  You can test that those two uses of *for* are not prepo­si­tions by
ex­chang­ing their in­ﬁni­tive clauses marked above for sim­ple noun complements:

- (1a) I [waited for]<sup>*phrasal verb*</sup> [day­light]<sup>*noun*</sup>.
- (2b) He [ar­ranged for]<sup>*phrasal verb*</sup> [travel]<sup>*noun*</sup>.

When you do that, *for day­light* and *for travel* are not prepo­si­tional
phrases be­cause they are not syn­tac­tic con­stituents.

Those two
in­ﬁni­tive clauses are not bare in­ﬁni­tives be­cause they have a *to*.
How­ever, some ma­trix verbs al­low for bare in­ﬁni­tive com­ple­ments
with­out that *to* marker:

- I made her come here.
- They saw me bake the cake.

Com­pare those with these, where you need the *to*:

- I forced her to come here.
- She wanted me to bake the cake.

Your sen­tences 3 and 4 do not con­tain prepo­si­tional phrases ei­ther.
They in­stead use *for* in a dif­fer­ent way than 1 and 2 do, this time to
mark the in­ﬁni­tive clause as the sub­ject of the main verb:

- (3) [For him to do that]<sup>*in­ﬁni­tive clause*</sup> took courage.
- (4) [For you to apol­o­gise]<sup>*in­ﬁni­tive clause*</sup> is not enough.

The *for* there is not part of the main verb; it’s a manda­tory marker of
the in­ﬁni­tive clause be­ing used as the the sub­ject of a tensed verb. You
can re­place both of those two sub­jects with the pro­noun *this* with no
change in meaning:

- (3a) This took courage.
- (4a) This is not enough.

Pro­nouns can stand in for noun phrases. They can­not stand in for prepo­si­tional
phrases, and in­deed a prepo­si­tional phrase “can­not” be the sub­ject of a clause.
They can only ful­ﬁll mod­i­fier roles in a sen­tence, not sub­stan­tive ones.

Be­cause we could make that swap here, those are not prepo­si­tional phrases. Another
in­di­ca­tion that this *for* is not a prepo­si­tion is that you can no more ex­change
it here for any other prepo­si­tion than you can ex­change *to* for one.

Lastly, if you re­ar­range the ﬁrst two sen­tences with the phrasal verbs
so that their in­ﬁni­tive clause becomes the main verb’s subject, now you
are forced to in­sert an “ex­tra” *for* to keep the sen­tence grammatical:

- (1c) *For* you to come here is what I waited *for*.
- (2c) *For* me to go there is what he ar­ranged *for*.

Now the ﬁrst and last words are both *for*. You need
both. These don’t work:

- (1d) *You to come here is what I waited for.
- (2d) *Me to go there is what he ar­ranged for.

And these are com­pletely un­gram­mat­i­cal be­cause they
are no longer the phrasal verbs from the original:

- (1e) For you to come here is what I *waited.
- (2e) For me to go there is what he *ar­ranged.

See also [this re­lated an­swer by John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278319/2085).

Comment: "I feel like treating for and to as complementizers of infinitives sometimes but prepositions other times may be confusing all this" – So... what are you saying – that we should think of _for_ as part of a complementiser in all cases? Or...? Again, I'm sorry for being slow... What do you think about the alternative analysis that I suggest in my second comment – that we have the PPs _for you_ and _for me_, functioning as PP complements, and that the subsequent infinitive clauses function as catenative complements?

Comment: I think phrasal-verbness is a bit of a red herring here. If you remove the subject from the infinitival clause, the _for_ becomes ungrammatical: “I waited [*for] to go” and “I arranged [*for] to go”, and the fact that removing _for_ in both 1d and 1e results in ungrammaticality rather proves that both _waited for_ and  _for X to Y_ are constituents (though the latter is not necessarily a PP). I don’t find 2e ungrammatical, incidentally, but I find 2b very odd; evidently, _arrange for_ is much less of a phrasal verb to me than to you.

Comment: @linguisticturn What about the coördination in *He arranged for [an early dinner] and [me to go there]*?  Is that grammatical?

Comment: (I don’t think linguisticturn will get that notification, will he? But for the record, it’s not grammatical to me. I would require “He arranged for an early dinner and for me to go there”. I’m guessing when a phrasal verb with the preposition _for_ knocks up against an infinitival complement with the subordinator _for_, the doubled _for_ gets reduced to one in order to avoid _for for_. I cannot think of any phrasal verbs with any other preposition which allow infinitival complements at all, though, so no minimal pairs.)

Comment: Your identification of "wait for" as a phrasal verb is not just "a red herring", as @JanusBahsJacquet says, but wrong. "the event for which you are waiting" with pied-piping of "for which" shows it is a prepositional phrase (so "for" is not part of the for-to complementizer, and "wait for" is not a phrasal verb).

Comment: @GregLee Then use *look for* and say: *They looked for me to finish dinner* > *For me to finish dinner is what they looked for* to get the doubling.  Pick a phrasal verb with *for*, whatever you consider those to be.

Comment: A preposition is lost before a complement object, whether the complementizer is for-to or "that".  I agree with you about the two "for"s in your example (1c), but the "for" that is lost when the complement comes after the verb is the preposition "for".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see that a comment I previously deleted actually got a reply from tchrist. Basically, I presented an argument that in (2), *for me to go there* is a constituent, whereas *arranged for* is not one. From the comments above, it seems to me we all agree that **if** this constituent structure is correct, then the 'phrasal verb' analysis of (2) can't work. So here's the argument for that constituent structure.

Comment: Consider *He wished for me to go there and arranged it, too.* The antecedent of *it* is *for me to go there.* (Isn't it?) But then *for me to go there* must be a constituent. Note that it can also enter into coordination with NPs, as in *He arranged [a nice dinner] and [for me to go there].* This immediately implies that *arranged for* is not a constituent, because we can't have overlapping constituents. (Though I seem to remember that at some point someone here was entertaining that option—many months ago—I for one don't want to go down that rabbit hole.)

Comment: A possible objection may be that you could also say *He wished for me to go there and arranged **for** it, too.* But all this would imply is that *me to go there* is a constituent. It doesn't contradict the fact that *for me to go there* is also a constituent, and so the conclusion that *arranged for* is not a constituent stands. Note also that the following coordination fails: * *He arranged for [a nice dinner] and [me to go there]* (we would have to put ***for** me to go there*).

Comment: (Though I see that there is some difference of opinion on that. But even if it turned out that this is acceptable after all, the case remains that coordination is not as good a test for constituent structure as proform substitution.) The only part of this that makes me uneasy is the result that *me to go there* is a constituent. It sounds wrong. Nevertheless, so far, I don't see it really contradicting anything, so I can live with it.

Comment: I don't see why you need to say that "me to go there" is a constituent.  I agree that "arranged for" in "arranged for it" is not a constituent.  If "arranged for" were truly a phrasal verb, you might expect *"arranged it for".

Comment: @GregLee I don't think you pinged  linguisticturn. Your *✱arranged it for* would be positing a ***separable + transitive*** phrasal verb, like in *call off* where you can have either *called his dogs off* or *called off his dogs*, and let its object fall in either position.  Intransitive phrasal verbs like *look for* cannot be separated in that fashion, so not being able to do it with *arrange for* seems not the best proof for what you want to say. But I grant you that *arrange for* doesn’t act like either of those, and will gladly concede your point that it’s not a phrasal verb.

Comment: @linguisticturn GregLee is pinging you from the vasty deep.

Comment: Right -- I was under the impression I was commenting on @linguisticturn's question.  Sorry.  I just learned from KarlG that there are inseparable phrasal verbs, at least in the sense that they have several words, but that doesn't mean that either "wait for" or "look for" are phrasal verbs.  I already argued that "wait for" is not, since it pied pipes.  "For which bus are you waiting?"  "For what streets are you looking?"  They're just verb + preposition combinations.  Why do you think they're phrasal verbs, anyway?

Comment: @GregLee I think *me to go there* is a constituent because it is the antecedent of *it* in *He wished for me to go there and arranged for it, too.*

Comment: @linguisticturn, By the same reasoning, is *I ... go there* a constituent in *I seemed to go there because he wished for it.* ?  (Answer: no, because underlying constituents can be broken up by transformations, like Raising.)

Comment: @GregLee So is *for me to go there* a constituent, then? I used the pro-form substitution to argue for that (and added an argument from coordination to strengthen the case), but now you're telling me that's more unreliable than I was led to believe. If it is a constituent, what's a good way to demonstrate that?

Comment: @linguisticturn, It's not so much an "unreliable" test as it is completely bogus.  I doubt that "me to go there" is a constituent.

Comment: @GregLee I'm not sure I follow. You are not saying that proform substitution tests are generally bogus? And OK, let's agree that *me to go there* is probably not a constituent. What about ***for** me to go there*?

Comment: @linguisticturn, I'm only saying what I said -- being an antecedent for definite anaphora doesn't show that a string of words is a constituent.  I agree with much of what you and tchrist have said in these answers and comments.  I don't pretend to know all about these structures.  I do think both of you have missed out on some unexpressed prepositions between verbs and following complements (sometimes the preposition "for" is lost before the complementizer "for").  I recall that McCawley investigates the internal surface structure of for-to complements, but I don't remember just what he says.

Comment: @GregLee OK, thanks! But I have a much more elementary question. Do you remember the argument you gave for the constituent structure of *a box of apples*, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/307884/155553)? What mistake am I making in the argument for the constituenthood of *me to go there* that isn't present in your argument for the constituenthood of *box of apples*?

Comment: @linguisticturn, if I had limited the scope of that old argument to indefinite anaphora, it might have been reasonable.  As it is, I'll confess that that previous argument of mine is mistaken.

Comment: @GregLee OK! Another question, if you don't mind. What is 'indefinite anaphora'? In [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/11517/11228), you say that it is a subtype of 'identity-of-sense anaphora'. From that answer I think I do understand the distinction between 'identity of sense' and 'identity of reference'. So 'indefinite abaphora' is an identity-of-sense anaphora such that…?

Comment: @GregLee I posted a separate question about all this, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482338/constituent-structure-of-he-arranged-for-me-to-go-there).

Comment: @tchrist [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482338/constituent-structure-of-he-arranged-for-me-to-go-there) should be settled before I can begin answering any other of the questions you posed.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is covered in some detail in Radford's *Analysing English Sentences* (p86-88). I am offering a synopsis here to complement the accepted answer by @linguisticturn.

---

The text extracts included below are from the *Complementisers* section of Radford's chapter *Words*, which sets out to "*explore how we determine what grammatical category a given word belongs to in a given use*".

Radford states that a complementiser is used to introduce a complement clause. He gives three examples:

> I think [*that* you may be right]
>
> I wonder [*if* you can help me]
>
> I am anxious [*for* you to receive the best treatment possible]

He notes the differences between complementisers *that/if* and *for*:

> ...*for* is an inherently infinitival complementiser, and so can be used to introduce a clause containing infinitival *to*, but not a finite clause containing a tensed auxiliary like (past tense) *should*:
>
> *I am anxious [*for* you should receive the best possible treatment]

After some discussion of the grammatical functions that complementisers serve, Radford asks whether:

> we really need to assign words such as *for/that/if* to a new category of _C/complementiser, or whether we couldn't simply treat (e.g.) *for* as a preposition... .
>
> The answer is 'No', because there are significant differences between complentisers and other apparently similar words. For example, one difference between the complementiser
>     *for* and the  preposition *for* is that the preposition *for* has substantive lexical semantic content and so (in some but not all of its uses) can be intensified by *straight/right*, whereas the complementiser *for* is a functor and can never be intensified: cf.
>
> > He headed *straight/right* for the pub [*for* = preposition]
> >
> > *He was anxious *straight/right* for nobody to leave [_for = complementiser]
>
> Moreover, the preposition *for* and the complementiser *for* also differ in their syntactic behaviour. For example, a clause introduced by complementiser *for* can be the subject of an expression like *would cause chaos* whereas a phrase introduced by a preposition cannot: cf.
>
> > *For him to resign* would cause chaos [=*for* clause]
> >
> > **For him* would cause chaos [=*for* phrase]
>
> What makes it even more implausible to analyse infinitival *for* as a preposition is the fact that (bold-printed) prepositions in English aren't generally followed by a [bracketed] infinitive complement, as we see from the ungrammaticality of:
>
> > *She was surprised **at** [there to be nobody to meet her]
> >
> > *I am not sure about **about** [you to be there]
> >
> > *I have decided **against** [us to go there]

There then follows a lengthy section discussing yet another difference between the preposition *for* and the complementiser *for*, namely that preposition *for* can be *pied-piped* whereas complementiser *for* cannot.

Radford concludes:

> So, there is considerable evidence in favour of drawing a categorical distinction between the preposition *for* and the complementiser *for*: they are different lexical items belonging to different categories.

With reference to the OP's sentences, we can say that Radford agrees with the CGEL  that *for* introduces a *to-infinitival* complement clause and is clearly not a preposition. Conversely, Radford calls *for* here a *complementiser*, whereas for the CGEL it is a *subordinator*.