# Can we have non-finite clauses with overt subject without "for"?

Tags: nonfinite-clause-complementation, catenative-verbs, for-to-complementizers

I read the following in a [comment to an answer to another post of mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481918/are-these-pps-or-non-finite-clauses-or-something-else-entirely?noredirect=1#comment1163515_481918):

"What’s the difference between *expect **for** things to improve* and e*xpect things to improve*? Is that *for* part of *expect for*, or is it part of the infinitive? You can do the same thing with *need **for** him to call* and *need him to call*, so I imagine there are others like this. You can *ask **that** he call you* and you can *ask **for** him to call you*, but you ask also *ask him to call you*. How come a *for* isn’t mandatory here in these *to*-infinitives with overt subjects?"

I think these are very interesting observations, and I too would like to have an answer to this. My very tentative theory is that these are, in fact, **different** syntactic structures – not simply the same structure with an optional *for*.

(1a) I expect **for things to improve**

(1b) I need **for him to call**

(1c) I asked **for him to call**

(2a) I expect **things to improve**

(2b) I need **him to call**

(2c) I asked **him to call**

My question is as follows: Could it be that whereas the structures following the finite verbs in (1a-c) are indeed non-finite clauses with overt subjects introduced by *for*, functioning as catenative complements, the words following the finite verbs in (2a-c) are, in fact, **two** constituents, where *things*, *him* and *him* respectively is a direct object in the form of an NP, whereas only the remaining structure constitutes a catenative complement in the form of a non-finite clause (without an overt subject)?

As for the construction with *that*, finally – as in *I asked that he call you* – I would've thought we're simply dealing with a finite *that*-clause (which happens to be in the subjunctive rather than in the indicative mood) functioning as a direct object – or am I completely lost here?

Comment: A quick observation. There does seem to be a semantic as well as syntactic difference between: _I asked him to call_ and _I asked for him to call_. In the former he is the person you from whom you request the call >> _John, please call me_. In the latter this is not necessarily the case >> _Please ask John to call me_.

Comment: @Shoe Yes, you're right :) I've taken out the bit about being semantically similar now. Thanks for pointing it out!